# ruby on rails custom route for button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to work out how to make a link_to or button_to when clicked trigger the following action that i have added to my controller

```
def send_notification
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id]).all
    @account_sid = '@@@@'
    @auth_token = '@@@@'# your authtoken here
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
    @account = @client.account

    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
      @users.each do |u|
        #Starts the SMS process
        #Uncomment to enable the SMS process
        team = truncate(u.team.name, :length => 15, :omission => '')
        opponent = truncate(@event.opponent.name, :length => 10, :omission => '')
        date = @event.datetime.strftime("%a, %e %b, %Y")
        time = @event.datetime.to_s(:event_time)
        location = truncate(@event.location.name, :length => 15, :omission => '')
        if u.mobile
          @message = @account.sms.messages.create({
                    :from => '+@@@@',
                    :to => "+#{phone_number(u.mobile, :Australia)}",
                    :body => "#{u.first_name}: #{team} v #{opponent} #{date} #{time}@ #{location}" })
          puts @message
        end
        @availability = u.availabilities.update(:unique_id => Base64.encode64("#{u.id.to_s}_#{@event.id.to_s}_#{@event.team.id.to_s}"))
        Notifier.event_added(u,@event).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

and i have added the below to my routes

```
resources :events do
    post 'send_notifications'
    get 'page/:event_page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
  end
```

output of rake routes
`event_send_notifications POST   /events/:event_id/send_notifications(.:format)`

view code
`=button_to 'Send Notifications' , event_send_notifications_path, :class => 'button'`

error
`No route matches {:action=>"send_notifications", :controller=>"events"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your controller action to `send_notifications`.
Your actions expects some parameters, so you should provide them too. Then, use it this way

```
=button_to('Send Notifications' , send_notifications_event_path(params), :action => 'send_notifications' , :class => 'button')
```

Here `param` is the hash of parameters, your action expects.

Also, make your action RESTful as

```
resources :events do
    post 'send_notifications', :on => :member
    get 'page/:event_page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
end
```

Let me know if it helps or if you get the same error again.

Comment: now getting `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events", :id=>"27"}`

Comment: Verify the route path in `rake routes`. Also, try `post 'send_notifications', :on => :member` once.

Comment: path from routes `event_send_notifications POST   /events/:event_id/send_notifications(.:format) events#send_notifications`

Comment: I just read your first comment carefully. Why is it saying `{:action=>"show"..`? This route is not for that path.

Comment: added the on :on => :member and the error isnt appearing, ill check to ensure its now calling that action

Comment: Great. Let me know, if it works. I'll then update my post. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29051/discussion-between-kiddorails-and-paul-whippet-mcguane)

Comment: since restarting the server i got this error `undefined method `event_send_notifications_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe64a59c238>:0x007fe64a6b1df8>`

Comment: Err. Please, check your `rake routes` again. Since this is a member route, I think your path should correspond to something like `send_notifications_event_path` or something, instead of this.

Comment: ah perfect :) i probably should have checked the route

Answer (score 0):

You've named your controller action `send_notification` (singular) but in routes used the plural `send_notifications`. You should choose one or the other and name them the same.

Comment: have you restarted your server?

Comment: should this be in my controller or in my model?

Comment: `send_notifications` method? It is in your EventsController, right? :)

Comment: make sure that in your events controller it says `def send_notifications` and use `send_notifications` in your routes.